# Firebase using queryEqualTo() two times

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following data structure in my database:

[image]

I do understand how to query for questions in one language like de:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("madeGames")
    ref.queryOrderedByChild("de").queryEqualToValue(true).observeSingleEventOfType(FIRDataEventType.Value) { (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in
        print("Data:", snap.value)
    }
```

**Problem:**

It seems to be impossible for me to just get games in de AND en from the server.

Of course I know I can first download all the de question and then loop throw them offline but that doesn't seem to be very intelligent for me.

Does anyone know how to do that more efficiency?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ZDHKwxRMiKQ, Follow this post, altho there is no solution provided by the firebase team yet... but keep checking...:)

Comment: You really can't query (multiple where queries) for more than one children in Firebase with any built in features. But, there are a number of ways to to this. @DavidEast created library that may be of interest [Querybase](https://github.com/davideast/Querybase)

Comment: @Jay thanks but Querybase also works as offline right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible option is to change your structure by combining the children properties into a single property like this.

```
made_games
   -jjjjsd903
      de_en: true
      de_fr: true
   -j090iQ0ss
      de: true
```

If you have a lot of languages you could also do this:

```
made_games
   -jjjjsd903
      language_available: 0   //just de
   -j090iQ0ss
      language_available: 3   //de_en

languages_available
    0: de
    1: en
    2: fr
    3: de_en
    4: de_en_fr
```

Edit - and another option I just thought of... go binary!

```
00000001 = en
00000010 = fr
00000100 = de
00001000 = du
00010000 = ge
```

Then to get any combination of languages, perform a bitwise 'or' operation on the two (or more) you want.

So to get en_de, it's 00001001. To get en_du_ge it would be 00011001. If you have 8 languages, that could be represented by 8 bits and 256 combinations. So if you have 11 languages, that would be 2^11 = up to 4096 combinations.

Using this technique you could avoid storing the en_fr etc totally and just search for the bitwised value.

You could store decimal versions of the binary numbers in Firebase... just showing the binary here for clarity.

Comment: I also thought of that but it will be mass of data if you have 50 languages you will have 2500 key value pairs to store

Comment: Disk space is cheap and 2500 isn't a lot to store. But.. to keep things tidy you may want to keep a reference to the combinations instead of keeping the data in each node, I updated my answer

Comment: @M.Kremer Had another thought that may work really well so I updated the answer.